# The Eigenvalues of a block matrix with nonzero blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a block matrix:
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\ C & D
\end{array}\right)
$$

Is there any relation between eigenvalues of $M$ and eigenvalues of matrices $A, B, C,$ and $D$?
I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices $A, B, C,$ and $D$, and I want to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$ with the information I have from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices $A, B, C,$ and $D$.

Comment: If $M$ is symmetric/Hermitian, you could perhaps use the results from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795). Otherwise, I'm not aware of any useful results here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No. It is not symmetric/Hermitian.

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for a function that inputs the eigenvalues of A,B,C,D and outputs the eigenvalues of M, no such function exists.
if A=D=0 and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then M has the eigenvalues {0,0,1,-1}. on the other hand, if A=B=C=D=0, then M has the eigenvalues {0,0,0,0}. in both cases, the eigenvalues of A,B,C,D are the same, yet M has different eigenvlaues.